# Find and Replace in bash Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Please advise on replacing a variable with latest date & time.

Here is my requirement.

```
FN='basename$0'

TS=`date '+%m/%d/%Y %T'`

QD='08/27/2014 16:25:45'
```

Then I have a query to run. After it has run, I need to take `$TS` (current system date & time)  and assign it as a value to the `$QD` variable. This is a loop process and gets updated every time the script runs.

I've tried using sed but was not successful.

Please help.

Comment: could you post the sed command you tried?

Comment: Umm... `QD="$TS"`? Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Although this is within the shell script...

Comment: Do post your code to tweak.

Comment: "#sed "s/\^QD=.*/QD="$TS"/g" "$FN"                                         
#echo $QD | sed -e "s/\^QD=.*/^QD="$TS"/g" "$FN"

Comment: if not sed ? any other logic to update the variable with current date & time ?

Comment: did you want to replace the date which was exists in the `QD` variable with the current one? if you use only `\^QD=` in your sed command, sed assumes QD as text not as a variable name.

Comment: All i need is to update $QD with latest system time after exection of a querry.

Comment: Any other suggestions please!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you haven't mentioned the overall goal that you wish to accomplish, I have a feeling something like this would be more robust than using `sed` to update an existing script file.

```
FN='basename$0'

TS=date '+%m/%d/%Y %T'

# Load the latest QD (from the last run)
[ -e ~/.QD.saved ] && QD="`cat ~/.QD.saved`"
QD='08/27/2014 16:25:45'
```

...Later in that file...

```
#Save the new QD variable
echo '$(date +$FORMAT)'" > ~/.QD.saved
```

Comment: Well the goal is to check the db query for errors. Once the query is executed the QD value must be updated to the latest so when the script runs again the it takes the time after the equerry was executed

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You have just assigned the present date to `TS` -- what is the difficulty in doing it again to `QD`. Also, I would recommend `QD=$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)` which produces a date-code that is easily sortable.

Comment: The query needs to run taking the time where it was executed earlier. The script runs every 15minutes

Answer (score 1):

Programatically modifying your script to have a different timestamp constant is **absolutely and emphatically** the wrong way to handle this problem.

Instead, when you want to mark that the query has been done, simply touch a file:

```
touch lastQueryCompletion
```

...and when you want to know when the query was last done, check that file's timestamp:

```
# with GNU date
QD=$(date -r lastQueryCompletion '+%m/%d/%Y %T')

# or, with Mac OS X stat
QD=$(stat -t '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S' -f '%Sm' lastQueryCompletion)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure if sed is the tool you're looking, I believe that your command would have to go like this:

```
sed -i -r 's/^QD=.*/QD="$TS"/g' "$FN"
```

I'm assuming you're using gnu-sed, which with -i option tells to do an *in-place* substitution, rather then copying the input line to the pattern space.

Well, hope it helps.